# I need a way to give multi variables and everytime call one randomly?

Tags: python

I am trying to make some adjustments on a code where I want the 'key' to be multiple keys and every time put a key.

```
key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
myfile = open("test.txt", "r")
for line in myfile:
    client = messagebird.Client(key)
    message = client.message_create(
          'idtest',
          (line),
          'Hi test',

        
      )
```

thats how i want the code to be like :

```
key1 = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
key2 = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
key3 = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    myfile = open("test.txt", "r")
    for line in myfile:
        client = messagebird.Client(" KEY1 THEN HE PUT KEY2 like random everytime ")
        message = client.message_create(
              'idtest',
              (line),
              'Hi test',
```

Comment: I think yes! sorry i wasn't even able to form a question to google it lol

Comment: You should probably take the time to go through some python tutorials. There's a whole bunch of decent ones a quick search away, and with some basic knowledge you know what to google for the more complex problems :)

Answer (score 1):

You could put all your keys in a list then use the choice method from the random module to select a key at random

[random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)

> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq. If seq is empty, raises IndexError

```py
from random import choice
keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
myfile = open("test.txt", "r")
for line in myfile:
    client = messagebird.Client(choice(keys))
    message = client.message_create(
        'idtest',
        (line),
        'Hi test',
```

Based on comments you can cycle through the keys by creating a cycle

[itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

> Make an iterator returning elements from the iterable and saving a copy of each. When the iterable is exhausted, return elements from the saved copy. Repeats indefinitely

```py
from itertools import cycle
keys = cycle(["key1", "key2", "key3"])
myfile = open("test.txt", "r")
for line in myfile:
    client = messagebird.Client(next(keys))
    message = client.message_create(
        'idtest',
        (line),
        'Hi test',
```

Comment: thank you so much bro, and if I may ask is there a way to give the keys in order then repeat the process?

Comment: So you mean like pick key 1, then key2, then key 3 then back to key 1 and keep looping?

Comment: yes bro exactly because i think if i keep it random the odds to hit same key is very high because they will be like 3 keys

Comment: updated with a second option that will cycle through the keys in order then loop back to the start and keep cycling as long as you need to.

Comment: thanks so much bro..